# Okay if our Internal Customer Service Software polls the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: discussion, api, abuse

We are in the process of creating a number of API's and extensible software which we expect will result eventually in questions being asked on stack overflow for working with our API's and extensible software frameworks. What we want to do is use the API to access any questions which are created with tags which we consider link with our software in order to post answers to questions made about our API or extensible software frameworks.

We would ideally be polling the stack overflow API at regular intervals to locate new questions asked and allow our customer service staff to post comments or answers to the questions asked. The software would not be taking any automatic action on the stack overflow API except for the regular polling of new questions and the only actions which result in content being posted back to stack overflow would be posted by a staff member, either as a manually applied pre-canned reply or custom written reply depending on the question being asked.

Would this be allowed under the terms for the API?

Comment: In general this seems fine. Except the "pre-canned reply" bit.  SE sites don't appreciate duplicates and if the same answer solves more than one question, then the correct thing to do is close the duplicate question(s).